# Multiple github repositories inside a single repository

Tags: git, github

I have multiple projects on github. Projects like ones for Android, Razer Switchblade, School etc.

I would like to sort them out in a way like this->

- Android (main repository)
  -----frameworks_base (sub repository)
  -----packages_apps_settings (another sub repository)
- School (main repository)
  -----project 1 (sub repository)
  -----project 2 (another sub repository)

To clarify:

In first example, it should be `MyUserName/Android/frameworks_base.git` and `MyUserName/Android/packages_apps_settings.git`.

Similarly in second example it should be `MyUserName/School/Project1.git` and `MyUserName/School/Project2.git`.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the root of your repo

```
git submodule add https://github.com/acme/Project1.git
git submodule add https://github.com/acme/Project2.git
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks. Submodules did the trick. I did read about submodules earlier but seems like I did the syntax wrong (the repository to be synced to to the repository to be synced from, I interchanged their places in command (by mistake). So it instead cloned into that folder inside my pc lol). But thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to start from the documentation for the submodules: [reference](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule).
Create a repository, as an example `School`, then add the others as submodules.
Enjoy. :-)